# Using Bootstrap table class with query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, class, html-table

I'm using a Bootstrap form to display a query result. I'd like the results to be formatted inside of a Bootstrap table.

I was told I could accomplish this by dropping in a '.label' in the bootstrap.css file and then using that class '< table class=".label" >' to create the style for the results.

I'm getting a string error instead. Any advice?

**UPDATE:** I'm aware of the table classes provided by Bootstrap to create the styles. What I'm attempting to do is apply these classes to the query. Right now I'm just using generic '< table >' code. You can't apply a Bootstrap class to this query and I was told I could instead drop a label in the "boostrap.css" original file that could then be used as the class for the table. Example: '< table class=".label" >'

Would I need to call out the bootstrap stylesheet on my PHP query file in order to accomplish this?

Is this possible?

**UPDATE (4/21/14):**

This is the code I'm currently using to produce a simple default table structure.  I'm wanting to use the table CSS Bootstrap provides listed at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

```
    return "<table>".$buf."</table>";
```

**UPDATE (4/21/14 - 3:30 p.m. ET):**

It turns out I was using the wrong code to get the CSS to respond. I should have been using "print" instead of "return" by mistake.  This code below did the trick.  The only issue I'm having now is getting the table to be responsive with the data inside.

```
    print "<table class='table-striped'>".$buf."</table>";
```

Comment: your question is unclear but bootstrap tables would be something like `<table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>` See [bootstrap-tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Comment: Updated my question above, hope it is more clear.

Comment: The question is still unclear a query returns data not HTML structures. Please post some code so we can get an idea of what your talking about also the period means class so it would not be .label it would just be label. The . Can be used to reference this class in CSS and jQuery ie $(".label") will return all selectors with the label class

Comment: I've updated my original question with the line of code I'm currently using to bring up a default table display. Thanks.